# childNodes ignore certain nodes

Tags: javascript

Certain texts do not seem to be text nodes at all.

In a contenteditable div, i want to wrap the content of a th in a paragraph.

I have the following HTML code :

```
<th class="section" colspan="4">Formule brute C<sub>10</sub>H<sub>14</sub>O</th>
```

In javascript, i have the following code :

```
var conteneur = document.querySelector('th');
var paragraphe = '';
for (const noeud of conteneur.childNodes) {
    if (noeud.nodeName.toLowerCase() != 'p') {
        if (paragraphe == '') {
            paragraphe = document.createElement('p');
            conteneur.insertBefore(paragraphe, noeud);
        }
        paragraphe.appendChild(noeud);
    }
    else {
        paragraphe = '';
    }
}
```

But instead of having this result :

```
<th class="section" colspan="4"><p>Formule brute C<sub>10</sub>H<sub>14</sub>O</p></th>
```

I have this result :

```
<th class="section" colspan="4"><p>Formule brute C<sub>10</sub><sub>14</sub></p>HO</th>
```

Note that the first text *Formule brute C* is indeed a text node since it is moved in the paragraph. But the *H* and the *O* are not out of place. It seems that the *H* and the *O* are not nodes at all, or are nodes but are purely ignored by childNodes ! Why ?

I had already noticed that, in a contenteditable div, certain texts are not considered as text nodes until you type text with your keyboard. And suddenly, the text becomes a text node! Very strange.

(the HTML code is an extract from my contenteditable div. The javascript code is an extract from a more complex function which is about all the contenteditable div. So i want keep this structure, use childNodes, nodeName… I just want to catch the *H*, the *O* and all the texts which are apparently not text nodes !)

I noticed that I also had a problem on other cells. For example, instead of having this :

```
<td><p><a href="https://link1.com">item1</a>, <a href="https://link2.com">item2</a>, <a href="https://link3">item3</a></p></td>
```

I have this :

```
<td><p><a href="https://link1.com">item1</a>, , </p><a href="https://link2.com">item2</a><a href="https://link3">item3</a></td>
```

This time, the two texts «, » are moved in the paragraph. They are indeed nodes. But the *a* tags are not moved. They are not nodes ??? It’s incomprehensible.

Comment: interesting, `conteneur.textContent` actually sees all text: `Formule brute C10H14O`. Can't find useful info about this anywhere, it just seems like `childNodes` stops seeing untagged text as soon as it encounters a tag (`sub`)

Comment: You actually spell node noeud instead of node??? Really!? `noeud of childNodes` - MDR Arnoeud !!!

Comment: It is just really funny. And weird and error prone to elaborately spell the node in french when the rest of the nodes in the statements are spelled node. And then naud in your name is spelled almost the same ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Damn, I found it. This is because childNodes returns a **live** list of child nodes. As I insert a paragraph into the *conteneur*, and I move the nodes in the paragraph one by one, the list of child nodes of the *conteneur* is no longer the same! In the loop, I lose one node out of two. Everything is explained.

Nobody noticed that!? pffff.

Here is the code :

```
function wrap_in_p (conteneur) {
    for (const noeud of conteneur.childNodes) {
         if (noeud.nodeName != 'P') {
            var paragraphe = document.createElement('p');
            conteneur.insertBefore(paragraphe, noeud);
            paragraphe.appendChild(noeud);
            while ( (paragraphe.nextSibling) && (paragraphe.nextSibling.nodeName != 'P') ) {
                paragraphe.appendChild(paragraphe.nextSibling);
            }
            wrap_in_p (conteneur);// reuse the function to reset the node list.
        }
    }
}
```

I would like to thank............... myself. :)

P.S.
You see Lajos Arpad and GrafiCode that it has nothing to do with HTML tags or whatever. I knew it.

Answer (score 1):

> TextNode objects contain only text content without any HTML or XML markup. TextNode objects make it possible to insert texts into the document as nodes

From here: http://help.dottoro.com/ljkuedch.php

Explanation: the key here is the **without any HTML or XML markup**. so, these items are not text nodes because the other HTML elements that they have as their siblings. I would therefore implement another solution:

```js
var conteneur = document.querySelector('th');
var paragraphe = document.createElement('p');
paragraphe.innerHTML = conteneur.innerHTML;
conteneur.innerHTML = paragraphe.outerHTML;
```

```html
<table>
<thead>
<th class="section" colspan="4">Formule brute C<sub>10</sub>H<sub>14</sub>O</th>
</thead>
</table>
```

Comment: "dottoro webreference" beats MDN here

Comment: Sorry, but it’s obvious that a text node has no HTML markup. So why the H and the O are not text nodes ? They are not in a HTML tag ! I dont understand how their siblings can modify that ? And i want use childNodes, nodeName… not innerHTML or outerHTML.

Comment: @Arnaud the inner text/html of their parent has markup, hence it's not a text node. I understand that you expect the texts between tags to be text nodes, but it's just not how they are being interpreted.

Comment: @Lajos What you say is false. The first text _Formule brute C_ is indeed a text node since it is moved in the paragraph ! So why the H and the O are not text nodes ?

Comment: @Arnaud is explained in the answer: `the other HTML elements that they have as their siblings`, meaning H and O are not child nodes, but siblings of <sub>s